# How to rotate a 2D theoretical path to fit or be overlaid on a path from videoprocessing

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, rotation, mathematical-optimization

I track the motion of an object from a video file in MATLAB and save the locations from each frame in a numberOfFrames x 2 array.

I know the theoretical path or intended path. When recording the movie the camera is at some unknown angle in space. Therefore, the path is skewed. The only information I have is the scaling between the pixels and millimeters by using the object diameter.

Now I would like to rotate the intended path, and move it around until it is overlaid on the tracked motion path.

I start with my theoretical path (Pth) then rotate it in 3-dimensions to "Pthr". After that I loop over each point in "M". And for each point in "M", I look for the closest point from "Pthr". Then, I repeat for the next point in "M". This probably has a problem of choosing the same point in "Pthr" for multiple points in "M".

I noticed this is sensitive to my initial guess and it gives terrible results.

Also, M is not a perfect path, since it is experimental measurements it is no where near perfect. [measured vs. theoretical unrotated path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x6EH.jpg)

```
% M = [Mx,My], is location in x and y, from motion tracking.
% scale = 20; % pixels/mm, using the size of object
% I build the theoretical path (Pth) goes from to (0,0,0) to (0,3,0) to
% (3,3,0) to (3,0,0) to be approximately the same length as M
Pthup = linspace(0,3,num)';
Pthdwn = linspace(3,0,num)';
Pth0 = zeros(size(Pthup));
Pth3 = 3*ones(size(Pthup));
% Pth is approximately same length as M
Pth = scale*[Pth0 Pthup Pth0;Pthup Pth3 Pth0;Pth3 Pthdwn Pth0];

% using fmincon in matlab to minimize the sum of the square
lb = [145 0 -45 min(min(M)) min(min(M))]; %upper bound
ub = [180 90 45  max(max(M)) max(max(M))]; %lower bound

coro = [180 0 0 mean(Mx) mean(My)]; %initial guess
% initial guess (theta(x),theta(y),theta(z), shift in x, shift in y)
cnt = 0; er = 1;
while (abs(er)>0.1)
    [const,fval] = fmincon(@(cor)findOrientation(cor,Pth,M),coro,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
    er = sum(const-coro);
    coro = const;
    cnt = 1+cnt;
    if (cnt>50)
        cnt = cnt;
        break
    end
end

%% function findOrientation keeps rotating Pth until it is closest to M

function [Eo] = findOrientation(cor,Pth,M)
% cor = [angle of rotations, center coordinate];(degrees, non-dimensiolaized in pixels)
% M = measured coordinates from movie in pixel
% coor: is output of the form [x-coordiante,y-coordinate, absolute distance from Center(i,:)]
% F = sum of least square, sum(coor(:,3))

%% Rotation of theoretical path about z,y,x and shifting in it in xy
thx = cor(1); 
thy = cor(2);
thz = cor(3);
xy = cor([4:5]);
% T = [cosd(thn) -sind(thn);
%         sind(thn) cosd(thn)]; %rotation matrix in 3D
Tz = [cosd(thz) -sind(thz) 0;
        sind(thz) cosd(thz) 0;0 0 1]; %rotation matrix
Ty = [cosd(thy) 0 -sind(thy);0 1 0;
    sind(thy) 0 cosd(thy)]; %rotation matrix
Tx = [1 0 0;0 cosd(thx)  -sind(thx);
    0 sind(thx) cosd(thx)]; %rotation matrix

Pthr = zeros(size(Pth));
for i = 1:size(Pth,1)
    xp = Tz*Pth(i,:)';
    xp = Ty*xp;
    xp = Tx*xp;
    Pthr(i,:) = xp.';
end

Pthr = Pthr(:,[1,2]); % omit third value because it is 2D
Pthr = Pthr + [cor([4:5])]; 

rin = sqrt(Pthr(:,1).^2+Pthr(:,2).^2); %theoretical radius
Centern = sqrt(M(:,1).^2 + M(:,2).^2);%measured radius


for i = 1:size(M,1) %loop over each point in tracked motion
    sub = Pthr-M(i,:); %subtracting M(i,:) from all Pthr
    for j = 1:length(sub)
        dist(j,1) = norm(sub(j,:));% distance from M(i,:) to all ri
    end
    %index is based on the min absolute distance between Pthr and M(i,:). It chooses the closest Pthr to a specific M(i,:)
    [mn, index] = min(dist); 
    erri = abs(rin(index)-Centern(i))./rin(index);
    coor(i,:) = erri;
end

Eo = sum(coor);
```